# Python convert dictionary into tuple

Tags: python, django-forms

How do I convert a dictionary into a tuple? Below is my dynamic dictionary.

```
genreOptions = GenreGuideServiceProxy.get_all_genres();
genreDictionary = {};
    for genre in genreOptions:
        genreDictionary[genre.name] = genre.name;
```

Comment: How do you want your tuple to look? You know about `genreDictionary.items()` method, right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
tuples = genreDictionary.items()
```

See http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items

Comment: Thanks, this works I just had to modify it a little. 

tuple(genreDictionary.items());

Answer (score 3):

Do you want to make (key, value) pairs? Here is code to generate a list of (key, value) tuples...

```
thelist = [(key, genreOptions[key]) for key in genreOptions]
```

Ahh I see there is a more efficient answer above...

```
thelist = genreDictionary.items()
```

But I want to include the list comprehension example anyways :)

Answer (score 1):

Check out [`dict.values`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values), [`dict.items`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items), and [`dict.iteritems`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.iteritems) for various ways to do this.

`dict.values` and `dict.items` return lists; `dict.itervalues` and `dict.iteritems` return iterators.